# compare two types in dictionary of types .net

Tags: .net, vb.net, comparison

I need to compare two dictionary values if the types stored are equal,
this is what i have

```
if gettype(Args(key)) = gettype(argtypes(key)) then
'' do something
end if
```

am getting an error

```
Type Args is not defined
```

pls can you help me with the problem

EDIT

Both dictionary where initially declared as

```
Dim dictionaryName As Dictionary(Of Object, Object)
```

Comment: Can you post the declaration of Args ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gettype` expects a type. You're giving it a value. To get the type of a value, call `GetType` on the value:

```
Args(key).GetType() = argtypes(key).GetType()
```